# Nested for loops - RadioButtonFor not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, linq, razor

I have nested foreach loops in my view, and am having problems with the radio buttons.

```
@foreach (var header in Model.surveyHeaders)
{
    <h1>@header.Name</h1>

foreach (var subHeader in Model.surveySubHeaders.Where(x => x.SurveryHeaderID == header.ID))
{
<h2>@subHeader.Name</h2>

    foreach (var question in Model.surveyQuestions.Where(x => x.SurveySubHeaderID == subHeader.ID))
    {
        @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.surveyResults.Where(y => y.SurveyQuestionID == question.ID).First().Value, 1);
        @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.surveyResults.Where(y => y.SurveyQuestionID == question.ID).First().Value, 2);
        @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.surveyResults.Where(y => y.SurveyQuestionID == question.ID).First().Value, 3);            
        @question.Question
    }
}
```

}

The radio button name is always 'Value', so the radio buttons are not grouped.  What can I do to achieve the grouping that is desired?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah collections in MVC, the joy! In order to make sure all fields are named accordingly in order to be correctly model bound on post, you need to use `for` loops, that will set the indexes correctly.

Before doing so, you're going to have to tweak your model structure to save your headaches. You need to re-arrange your logic so that you have a hierarchical object model in which you can iterate more cleaner (this way we're getting away from logic in the view too!)

Your survey header class, can't you put a list of subheaders on it? Then your subheader class, can you put the list of questions for that subheader? That way you can do:

```
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.SurveyHeaders.Count; i++)
{
    <h1>@Model.SurveyHeaders[i].Name</h1>

    for (var j = 0; j < Model.SurveyHeaders[i].SubHeaders.Count; j++)
    {
        <h2>@Model.SurveyHeaders[i].SubHeaders[j].Name</h2>

        for (var k = 0; k < Model.SurveyHeaders[i].SubHeaders[j].Questions.Count; k++)
        {
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.SurveyHeaders[i].SubHeaders[j].Questions[k].Value , 1);
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.SurveyHeaders[i].SubHeaders[j].Questions[k].Value , 2);
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.SurveyHeaders[i].SubHeaders[j].Questions[k].Value , 3);            
            @Model.SurveyHeaders[i].SubHeaders[j].Questions[k].Question
        }
    }
}
```

This assumes your new model structure is something like (with the following classes):

```
public class MyModel
{
    public List<SurveyHeader> SurveyHeaders { get; set; }
}

public class SurveyHeader
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<SubHeader> SubHeaders { get; set; }
}

public class SubHeader
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Question> Questions { get; set; }
}

public class Question
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
    public string Question { get; set; }
}
```

Also one other tip, for future reference, you use the following LINQ in your code:

```
x => x.surveyResults.Where(y => y.SurveyQuestionID == question.ID).First().Value
```

You can simplify it because `First` can actually take a lamba, like so (although you should use `FirstOrDefault` and null check it in future just for safety):

```
x => x.surveyResults.First(y => y.SurveyQuestionID == question.ID).Value
```

Comment: No problems! Glad I could help, boy knows I needed it when I first encountered this type of problem at work :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use the overload of the RadioButtonFor extension that takes in HtmlAttributes and set the name of each of the RadioButtons.

Comment: I tried this. Id can be overwritten, but it didn't work for name.

Comment: @Jason I would still try it with id

Comment: @COLDTOLD I did, but radio buttons are grouped by the name attribute, so it had no effect.